# Xamarin ios error: NullReferenceException

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am getting this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance 
of an object
at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession  +
 <MaybeConvertToLatestXcode>c__async5.MoveNext () [0x0004c] in 
 /Users/builder/data/lanes/4470/6c2f6737/source/md-
 addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/
 IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:774 
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () 
[0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-
3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-
x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/
exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess 
(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-
mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-
x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/
TaskAwaiter.cs:187
```

I cannot view my storyboard.

Comment: Did this error occur in a new project? Have you tried to remove the storyboard file and create a new instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it better to address this issue to xamarin support.

For now, you can try to open your storyboard in XCode.

Comment: does anyone have any ideas ?